# preload input type image

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I preload images when they are defined "within" an input type in the html layout like this:

```
<input type="image" src="bla.png" id="myimage1" data-url="Myurl" />
```

I see so many samples with the img-tag but not the input of type image.

Comment: What would be different, both are still image files? What are you trying to do with the preload with this tag?

Comment: the *purpose* of preloading these isn't clear.

Comment: I want to know how I can add/append this image object to an existiaing input of type image? I want to make the images or input of type image initially hidden. Then when they are loaded show them by fading in one image after the other etc...

Comment: I need to disable the input of type image theirfore I can not use normal imagas like the img-tag. Only an input can be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    var img = new Image ();
    img.src =  $('#myimage').data('url');
});
```